# Extract base64 encoded data from a PhoneGap FileEntry

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I'm using Phonegap 2.0 and try to get a media encoded as base64 from its URI with no success.

```
function tryToSend(fileReader) {
    // I don't really what the parameter is
}

function win(file) {
    alert(file.name + ' ' + file.type); // type is undefined here
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = tryToSend;
    var encoded = reader.readAsDataURL(file); // encoded is undefined here
}

function fail(error) {
    console.log(error);
}

function onResolveSuccessCompleted(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(win, fail);
}

function onResolveFailed(error) {
    console.log(error);
}

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(MY_FILE_URI, onResolveSuccessCompleted, onResolveFailed);
```

At the end, i'm not able to extract base64 encoded data for my file, I need it to send it in a JSON AJAX call.

Is there something wrong in my code? Do you know a way to achieve what I need?

Cheers.

Cyril

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, there is no point to capturing the return value of reader.readAsDataURL as it is an async call and does not return anything. Your tryToSend method should be written:

```
function tryToSend(evt) {
    var encoding = evt.target.result;
    // now encoding has your file as a base64 encoded string.
}
```

Comment: It's working, I tried evt.result but obviously I was missing something... Cheers!